# Getting a ParseUser from a List<ParseUser> using Parse SDK for android?

Tags: android, list, get, parse-platform

Using the Parse SDK for android, I'm trying to receive a ParseUser from a query, the following code is what I have tried:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

Follow.include("author");
query.whereEqualTo("User", "Alex"); 
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {       
public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
if (e == null) {
// This is where I want to receive the ParseUser from the List<ParseUser>
ParseUser pu = objects.get("author");
} else {

}


} });
```

Object.get("author") creates errors.

Thankyou for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ParseUser pu = objects.get("author"); would be incorrect usage. Get method is generally used to get a object at a particular position in the list.
```

The query returns a list of ParseUsers which you have named as objects.
Now use an iterator to go through the list to access each ParseUser.

like this

```
for(ParseUser pu : objects){
       //access the data associated with the ParseUser using the get method
       //pu.getString("key") or pu.get("key") 
}
```

Hope this helps!